# For $n \geq 6$ how many permutations $p_{1}p_{2}...p_{n}$ are there such that at least one of $p_{1}$, $p_{2}$, $p_{3}$ are even?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I'm sort of stuck, not exactly sure how to do this problem. I considered counting how many possible ways there are when $n=6$ for example and got:

3*2*1*3*2*1 + 3*3*2*4*3*2*1 + 3*3*5*4*3*2*1

Comment: **Hint:** Try counting how many permutations there are such that *none* of $p_1,p_2,p_3$ are even.

Comment: I will point out as well that your answer is most definitely wrong since the last term $3\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1$ is greater than $6!$, the total number of permutations on six elements.  You are trying to count a particular subset of the permutations on six elements and so must be smaller than $6!$.

Comment: There are 36 permutations on 6 symbols where none of $p_{1}$, $p_{2}$, $p_{3}$ are even. In this case it was $\frac{n}{2}! \times \frac{n}{2}!$

Comment: Counting how many have none of them even.  Pick the first number.  It must be odd so this can be done in ____ ways.  Pick the second number.  It also must be odd and different than previous so this can be done in ____ ways.  Pick the third number in _____ ways.  Now, arrange the remaining $n-3$ elements in the remaining spots in _____ ways.  Apply multiplication principle.

Comment: First number can be pick in 3 ways, second 2 ways, last in 1 way. The remaining spots are 3! ways. I don't get it.

Comment: That is correct for specifically $n=6$.  What about for $n=10$?  What about for $n=11$?  How about for *arbitrary $n$ where we don't know the exact value of $n$, which is what the question you are asked about actually is*.  Once you know how many permutations out of the total are "bad", how do we use this for finding number that are *good*?

Comment: If $n$ is even then it's $\frac{n}{2}\times(\frac{n}{2}-1)\times (\frac{n}{2} -2)\times (n-3)!$. We can subtract this from $n!$. For general $n$ we can floor $\frac{n}{2}$.

Comment: Whether we floor $n$ or ceiling $n$ will depend on if we are permuting the elements of $\{0,1,2,3,\dots,n-1\}$ or if we are permuting the elements of $\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$.  Otherwise, that is correct.

Comment: Sorry I meant ceiling of $\frac{n}{2}$. Seems to work perfectly, thanks.